# Twitter Bootstrap Grid with Detail View

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a grid that allow me to create a subgrid and show some details, like this [link](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid22_demo.html).

It's ok, it's working, but right now I need to use Twitter Bootstrap grids, with this functionality.

Does anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to apply bootstrap styling to your grid or trying to actually convert your tables to a set of divs implementing the Boostrap Grid System?

Comment: It must still be a grid with that kind of functionality, but with bootstrap grid.

Comment: Why do you want to use twitter bootstrap grid? Style?

Comment: Yes, but also because it has native compatibility with mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter bootstrap grids are on a 12-column system within a row. You can nested grid systems like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span5">
        The width of this div is 5/12ths of the width of its row.
    </div>
    <div class="span7">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">
                 This is half of the width of the nested row, 
                 which is then 7/12ths of the width of its parent row
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it doesn't help me a lot. I need a way to do this dynamically, just like the example in the question.

Comment: Why don't you just generate the bootstrap grid with jQuery or other javascript?

Comment: Also, you should really mention "dynamic" in the question if you expect that to be part of the answer.

Comment: You said "grid that allow me to create a subgrid and show some details". That link has that. Being dynamic is unrelated to what you said you were trying to do. If you want it to be dynamically generated, you should say "Dynamically generated, like in this link". Regardless, why can't you use jQuery?

Comment: I thought it was implied. Anyway, I can use JS, but I was looking for a working JS to use the same way I use that example. Thanks for the replies.